# Tails of a Conditional Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, distribution-tails

Let $X \sim N (0, \sigma^2)$ and $Y ~ \sim N(0, 1 + \sigma^2)$ be independent. I'm trying to understand and visualize the function
$$f(x) := P(X > Y + x | X > x),$$
for large $x$ (say, $x > 3 \sigma$). For example, for $\sigma = 1$, what is $P(X > Y + 5 |  X > 5)$?
I have run some large simulations and my suspicion is that as $x \to \infty$, $f(x)$ converges to a constant in (0, 1), but I'm stuck as to how to evaluate, approximate, or visualize this function.

Comment: To find the limit, consider that
$$f(x) = \mathbb P(Y < 0) + \frac
 {\int_{\mathbb R^+} \, (1 - F_X(x + y)) f_Y(y) \, dy} {1 - F_X(x)}, \\
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac
 {\frac d {dx} \int_{\mathbb R^+} \, (1 - F_X(x + y)) f_Y(y) \, dy}
 {\frac d {dx} (1 - F_X(x))} =
\int_{\mathbb R^+} \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac
 {f_X(x + y) f_Y(y)} {f_X(x)} \, dy$$
(since $f_X(x + y)$ and $f_X(x + y)/f_X(x)$ are bounded on $(\mathbb R^+)^2$).

Answer (score 1):

For your example if $X\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(0, 2)$ then $$\begin{align}P(X>Y+5|X>5)&=P(X>Y+5,Y>0|X>5)+P(X>Y+5,Y\le0|X>5)\\
&=P(X>Y+5|X>5,Y>0)P(Y>0)+P(X>Y+5|X>5,Y\le0)P(Y\le0)\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_{Y+5}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{P(X>5)}\frac{g(y)}{P(Y>0)}dxdy\cdot \frac 12+1\cdot \frac 12\end{align}$$

Comment: Got it, thanks!